# Residue of a local $\gamma$-factor and its relation with adjoint $\gamma$-factor

Tags: automorphic-forms, reductive-groups, langlands-conjectures

I met the following relation (if my understanding is correct) of local $\gamma$-factors when I was reading Hiraga-Ichino-Ikeda's paper "Formal Degrees and Adjoint $\gamma$-Factors": Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field with residue field order $q$. Let $G=GL(n,F)$ and $\pi$ be a discrete series of $G$, $\tilde{\pi}$ its contragredient. Then
$$Res_{s=0}\gamma (s,\pi\times \tilde{\pi},\psi)=(\log q)^{-1}(1-q^{-1})\gamma(0,\pi,Ad,\psi)^{-1}.$$
Here the $\gamma$-factor is defined in the usual sense according to local Langlands correspondence ($L$-parameters, Artin $L$-functions, and local root number/$\epsilon$-factors), and $Ad$ means the adjoint representation of the $L$-group on its own Lie algebra.

I saw this relation in that paper, at the end of the proof of the lemma 4.1 (if my understanding is correct). It seems that the authors regarded this as a very direct fact and gave no more explanation. But I have no idea how left hand side is related to the adjoint $\gamma$-factor of $\pi$. Does this follow from some routine properties or calculations of local Langlands correspondence? Thanks a lot in advance for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

The equality they used in the paper should be
$$\mathrm{Res}_{s=0}\gamma(s,\pi\times\widetilde{\pi},\psi)^{-1}=(\log q)^{-1}(1-q^{-1})\gamma(0,\pi,Ad,\psi)^{-1}.$$

Notice that the difference between L-factors $L(s,\pi\times\widetilde{\pi})$ and $L(s,\pi,Ad)$ is $L(s,triv)$,
where $triv$ stands for the trivial representation.
Hence we get
$$\gamma(s,\pi,Ad,\psi)\gamma(s,\pi\times\widetilde{\pi},\psi)^{-1}=L(s,triv)L(1-s,triv)^{-1}.$$
Directly from the definition of local L-factors we have:
$$L(1,triv)=(1-q^{-1})^{-1},~\mathrm{Res}_{s=0}L(s,triv)=\mathrm{Res}_{s=0}\frac{1}{1-q^{-s}}=(\log q)^{-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess the point here is that I don’t know the relation $\gamma(s,\pi,Ad,\psi)\gamma(s,\pi\times\widetilde{\pi},\psi)^{-1}=L(s,triv)L(1-s,triv)^{-1}.$ Does it come from some concrete computations of the Rankin-Selberg theory?

Comment: @tooweaktolearnmathematics No, this step is just from the definition of $\gamma$-factors. The quotient turns out to be the $\gamma$-factor of the trivial representation and the $\epsilon$-factor becomes trivial.